# Memory Management for Mapped Data in Shared Memory Segments

Tags: c, linux, posix, shared-memory, mmap

I'm working on a project in C that uses shared memory for IPC on a Linux system.  However, I'm a little bit confused about memory management in these segments.  I'm using the POSIX API for this project.

I understand how to create the shared segments, and that these persist until a reboot if you fail to properly remove them with `shm_unlink()`.  Additionally, I understand how to do the actually mapping & unmapping with `mmap` and `munmap` respectively.  However, the usage of these operations and how it affects the stored data in these shared segments is confusing me.

Here is what I'm trying to properly understand:

Lets say I create a segment using `shm_open()` with the `O_CREAT` flag.  This gives me a file descriptor that I've named `msfd` in the below example. Now I have a struct that I map into that address space with the following:

```
mystruct* ms = (mystruct*)mmap(NULL, sizeof(mystruct), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, msfd, 0);
//set the elements of the struct here using ms->element = X as usual
```

**Part 1)**
Here's where my confusion beings.  Lets say that this process is now done accessing that location since it was just setting data for another process to read.  Do I still call `munmap()`?

I want the other process to still have access to all of this data that the current process has set.  Normally, you wouldn't call `free()` on a `malloc`'ed pointer until its use is no longer needed permanently.  However, I understand that when this process exits the unmapping happens automatically anyway.  Is the data persisted inside the segment, or does that segment just get reserved with it's allotted size and name?

**Part 2)**
We're now in the process of the other application that needs to access and read from that shared segment.  I understand that we now open that segment with `shm_open()` and then perform the same mapping operation with `mmap()`.  Now we have access to the structure in that segment.  When we call `munmap()` from this process (NOT the one that created the data) it "unlinks" us from that pointer, however the data is still accessible.  Does this assume that process 1 (the creator) has *NOT* called `munmap()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the data persisted inside the segment,

Yes.

> does that segment just get reserved with it's allotted size and name?

Also yes.

> Does this assume that process 1 (the creator) has NOT called munmap()?

No.

The shared memory gets created via `shm_create()` (as being taken from available OS memory) and from this moment on it carries whichever content had been written into until it is given back to the OS via `shm_unlink()`.

`shm_create()` and `shm_open()` act system oriented, in terms of the (shared) memory being a system (not process) specific resource.

`mmap()` and `unmap()` act process oriented, that is map and unmap the system resource shared memory into/out-of the process' address space.